# 3D model outline (emissive texture) doesn’t move with rigged 3D model blender 3.5

Tags: animation, 3d, game-development, blender

I’m working on a 3D model in blender 3.5 and have started the rigging process. My 3D model has 2 textures. One of the textures is a black emissive texture with solidify modifier to achieve a black outline of the model (method used is in this video https://youtu.be/voF6VlJ0mPI). I’ve applied the modifier and don’t think I can undo it at this point, as far as I know.

My rig seems to be working well but there’s one big issue being that the outline is not moving with the model when I manipulate the armature. I’m very new to 3D art so I might be missing something simple. I would appreciate any help, I struggled to find answers searching online.

Thus far I’ve only tried weight painting, but I’m not sure I’m doing it correctly/if it’s even affecting the outline. If weight painting is the solution here, is there a good resource on how to do so, or could someone briefly describe how I can weight paint the outline for my model?

Thank you!